# Creating a list or range with all numbers up to a certain variable

Tags: python, list, variables

So I am defining a function that takes in one variable R. Then I need to create a list of all integers from 0 to R (in the context of the problem R will always be positive).

EX) When I do

```
R=5
print(list(0,R))
```

I just get a list with 2 elements: 0 and 5, but I want 0,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: So `list(range(0, R+1))`?

Comment: _`print(list(0,R))` I just get a list with 2 elements: 0 and 5, but I want 0,1,2,3,4,5_ - actually you get `TypeError: list expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`

Answer (score 0):

The range() function returns a sequence of numbers, starting from 0 by default, and increments by 1 (by default), and stops before a specified number.
range(6) would return [0,1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Techically `range()` will return `range` object, not `list`